# Stange missing libraries when linking

Tags: programming, dynamic-linking

When developing with Qt or plain C++, my linker yields "Cannot find: -lGL"
I have checked the existence of the libraries and their use by ld with `ldconfig -p |grep libGL`:

> libGLdispatch.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) =>
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0
> ...
> libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
> libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1

Other libraries will link without issues.

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: It is the latest Ubuntu LTS 20.04

Comment: The build-time linker (`ld`) probably expects to find a symbolic link `libGL.so -> libGL.so.1` - do you have the `libgl-dev` package installed, or just the runtime packages? What does `pkg-config --libs gl` say?

Comment: Yes that was it, `pkg-config --libs gl`:  
Package GL was not found in the pkg-config search path.  
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `GL.pc'  
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable  
No package 'GL' found  

`sudo ln /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` fixed it.  
Thanks.